# Flutter - Function is called OnTap: but not with Ontap () {...}

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, ontap

I'm pretty inexperienced with Flutter, I created a widget with this piece of code inside:

With code written like this: (the ToolModify function is not called)

```
final VoidCallback ToolModify;


onTap: () {
  // rest of the code
  widget.ToolModify;
},
```

Instead, it is called with code written like this:

```
onTap: widget.ToolModify,
```

Can anyone explain to me why this happens?

Since I need to write other lines of code besides widget.ToolModify; how can i call the ToolModify function inside OnTap: () {...}  ??

Hope someone can help me. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is perfectly legal and good style to code like this:

```
onTap: widget.ToolModify,
```

In this case, `widget.ToolModify` denotes a function and you assign the function to `onTap` to make `onTap` **call the function later on**.

If you call it like this, you make a new anonymous and parameterless function `() {}` that just calls the other function `widget.ToolModify()`:

```
onTap: () {
  widget.ToolModify(); 
},
```

Note, that `widget.ToolModify` **denotes the function itself**. While `widget.ToolModify()` calls the function with no parameters.

Moreover, you may write this, since you return **just one expression**:

```
onTap: () => widget.ToolModify(),
```

**Example**

Have a look at this example that defines a **function ad(), that returns an anonymous function** and later on applies it to some arguments:

```
  // This function takes one argument x and returns a new function
  // of one parameter
  Function(int) add( y ) {
    return ( x ) => ( x + y );
  }
  
  // The above => notation is only applicable, if exactly one expression is returned
  // In case the structure of the inner function is more complex, write
  // it using non shorthand notation like so
  Function(int) divideBy( y ) {
    return ( x ) {
      assert( y > 0 );
      return ( x / y );
    };
  }
  
  // Use the above function to create two specialist functions
  Function(int) add100 = add( 100 );
  
  // Simmilar, but implicitly typed
  var add10 = add( 10 );
  
  var halfOf = divideBy( 2 );

  var doubleOf = divideBy( 0.2 );


  // Now apply two specialized functions
  print( add10( 1 ) );
  print( add100( 1) );
  
  print( halfOf( 10 ) );
  print( doubleOf( 10 ) );
```

Outputs this:

```
11
101
5
50
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to actually call the method:

```
onTap: () {
  // rest of the code
  widget.ToolModify(); // notice the brackets
},
```

Comment: Not wrong, but kind of misleading.